# Is it possible to have a data frame in which cells contain lists?

Tags: types, dataframe, cell, pandas

We can imagine data frame as a table. Different cells contain values of different types (integer, real, strings). I wonder if it is possible to have a data frame in which some cells contain lists (or, alternatively, series).

**ADDED**

I am interested in this question in the context of the `groupby` operation. If we apply this operation to a data frame, as a result we do not get another data frame. I wonder why not. Why not to have another data frame that has lists as values for some cells?

Comment: I'm really not sure I understand what you are asking in the "update" to this question, it reads like a different question rather than an edit. There could be something in it (it could be interesting), but at the moment it looks not-constructive, so I think it's worth asking as a separate question and thinking up [an example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndyHayden Hayden, in the "update" I explain why I ask my question (why it is interesting to me to know the answer). The update is not a new question. The question-sentence from the update was just a rhetorical question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([[list('ABC')]])

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
           0
0  [A, B, C]
```

*Note: the dtype for this column is `object`.*

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're talking about with respect to groupby and lists?

```
In [21]: df
Out[21]:
   0  1
0  a  0
1  b  1
2  a  2
3  b  3
4  a  4
5  b  5
6  a  6
7  b  7
8  a  8
9  b  9

In [22]: df.groupby(0).agg(lambda x: x.tolist())
Out[22]:
                 1
0
a  [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
b  [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```